# Pythonic way to wrap overloaded c++ constructor using Cython

Tags: python, c++, cython

I'm wrapping a C++ class with Cython into an extension type to be used in Python. This class has an overloaded constructor that allows three different ways to construct an instance by referencing filenames and existing objects. Here's an example of the c++ declarations:

```
myCppClass()
myCppClass(char * filename, cppObj1 obj1)
myCppClass(char * filename, cppObj2 obj2, cppObj1 obj1)
myCppClass(cppObj3 obj3, cppObj2 obj2, cppObj1 obj1)
```

Now I have made extension types for `cppObj1`, `cppObj2`, and `cppObj3`, that have the simple structure:

```
cdef Class pyObj:
    cdef cppObj *_cppObj
    def __cinit__(self):
            self._cppObj = new cppObj()
    def __dealloc__(self):
        def self._cppObj
```

I want users to be able to create an extension type of `myCppClass` from python using these. Since there is no overloading in Python, I'm not sure the best way to implement this. Right now I have something like:

```
from cython.operator import dereference as deref

cdef Class myPyClass:
    cdef myCppClass *_myCppClass
    def __cinit__(self, filename=None, pyObj3 obj3=None, pyObj2 obj2=None, pyObj1 obj1=None):
        if (filename is not None) and (obj1 is not None) and (obj2 is None) and (obj3 is None):
            self._myCppClass = new myCppClass(<char*>(filename.encode()), deref(obj1._cppObj1))
        elif (filename is not None) and (obj1 is not None) and (obj2 is not None) and (obj3 is None):
            self._myCppClass = new myCppClass(<char*>(filename.encode()), deref(obj2._cppObj2), deref(obj1._cppObj1))
        elif (filename is None) and (obj1 is not None) and (obj2 is not None) and (obj3 is not None):
            self._myCppClass = new myCppClass(deref(obj3._cppObj3), deref(obj2._cppObj2) deref(obj1._cppObj1))
        else:
            raise ValueError
    def __dealloc__(self):
        def self._myCppClass
```

However, I think this is not a very good solution. It's very rigid, and the biggest issue is that it's error prone if a user forgets to use keyword arguments. A nicer way might be to require keyword arguments by doing something like

```
cdef Class myPyClass:
    cdef myCppClass *_myCppClass
    def __cinit__(self, init_mode, **kwargs):
        if init_mode == "mode1":
            # Use 1st constructor, getting arguments from kwargs
        elif init_mode == "mode2":
            # Use 2nd constructor, getting arguments from kwargs
        elif init_mode == "mode3":
            # Use 3rd constructor, getting arguments from kwargs
        else:
            raise ValueError
    ...
```

However, I don't think there's a way to store extension types in the Python dictionary kwargs to get access to their c++ attributes. I recently learned that placing a * as the first argument enforces keyword arguments in Python3, perhaps this is a viable solution?

Should I just avoid trying to mimic overloading altogether and make one method for each initialization?

```
cdef Class myPyClass:
    cdef myCppClass *_myCppClass
    def __cinit__(self):
        self._myCppClass = new myCppClass()
    def initMode1(self, filename, pyObj1 obj1):
        # Call constructor
    def initMode2(self, filename, pyObj2 obj2, pyObj1 obj1):
        # Call constructor
    def initMode3(self, pyObj3 obj3, pyObj2 obj2, pyObj1 obj1):
        # Call constructor
    ...
```

Comment: I don't know about Cython per se, but in regular Python you can define "alternative constructors" for a class which are `classmethod`s that create instances of the class like the `__init__()` method does, but typically have calling sequences which are different from it. An example in the standard library is the `namedtuple` [`_make()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.somenamedtuple._make) method.

Comment: I'd do this with classmethods. Cython will support the `*` all subsequent arguments are keyword only though (even on Py2)